# Framework similar to Adobe Flex with HTML5

Tags: apache-flex, html

is there a framework that is similar to Adobe Flex written in HTML5?

My app currently support having multiple objects on the screen where user can drag / drop / resize and rotate them in scrapbook fashion. There are few animations as well. Flex makes it easy to build such apps. I was wondering if there is a good framework I can use to ease up such task maybe with HTML5 so it can be used on mobile devices.

Comment: Maybe you should look into HaXe

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns haXe is not a framework. It's just another language that lets you compile into AVM bytecode (Flash), JavaScript and some other options.

Comment: There's no HTML 5 framework that can completely match Flex on all terrains (it would make Flex more or less obsolete if there were). With just a few adjustments you could run your Flex app as an AIR app and so deploy it to all devices. But perhaps that is not an option for you?

Comment: @RIAstar: of course, I know HaXe is not a framework, but I think there's nothing similar to Flex. With HaXe maybe he can at least write a code similar to AS3: http://www.haxenme.org/

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am author of Web Atoms JS

Look at image and tell me if looks different then flex. In any other framework you will end up writing lots of script, where in flex you had advantage of creating mark up.

Web Atoms JS was built to bring all concepts of Flex, Silverlight and XUL. And each of these technologies used more of XML markup for very high level UI controls. Screens become complex and visualizing them becomes painful when it keeps on changing.

With Web Atoms you will write for less code then any of other frameworks.

This is a Sample of what all things are possible in Web Atoms JS.

Here is link to documentation.
http://webatomsjs.neurospeech.com/docs

[image: Flex to HTML]

Answer (score 1):

I'm working for a company that uses Flex with BlaseDS (for server communication), and now they want to realize a POC (Proof Of Concept) for a new framework that can replace Flex. and now we are putting Sencha frameworks (Ext JS & Sencha Touch) and other frameworks under the microscope, and from my short experience I share this with you:

**Flex**

- Based on Flash Player so you can not run a flex based applications before you install the Flash Player plugin. Maybe this is not a big problem now, but if the Flash market share is decreasing so this -in my openion- will be a problem.
- The Flex SDK (with other frameworks) are now moving from Adobe to [Apache](http://flex.apache.org), and I think this is altering the community confidence.

**Sencha**

- Offer frameworks based in HTML5/JS/CSS3 (Web Standards) that are supported by W3C.
- Sencha team offers guids (Webinars, Tutorials, ...) for moving from flex to Sencha frameworks (look at this for more information [flex-to-sencha](http://pages.sencha.com/flex-to-sencha.html)).

I'm not against Flex, because it has a very good maturity level, and use Flex or Sencha depends in the context of each company.

Hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/). It has a lot of the niceties of Flex (a large component library, data binding, MVC framework).